# SharePoint 2007 Out of the Box Doc Lib Alert/Comment section Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have ran into the following problem and am completely stumped. When I upload a document (this case excel file) to an OOTB SharePoint doc lib there is the option to add a comment. The problem is, that I have used this same excel file for multiple uploads and when I try to upload it again, even under a new name (giving the file a new name on my computer), when I try to upload it the comment section stays the same, 'Still not much open question.' 
After I upload the document, in the doc lib the comment column changes to what I changed it to, but the email alert comes in as the original, outdated comment. 
I cannot figure out why it retains this old comment in the alerts and is auto(stuck) in there every time I go to upload this file even after changing the name. This hasn't occurred with other excel files. (I do not know what is going on, if it is from the Excel file itself or if it is prob with the doc lib, or an alert issue.) 
Does anyone have any ideas? I am simply at a loss now. 
Thanks!